# Is execution of static method of a class in multi-threaded program thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a static method in a class that runs some calcs, here is code snippet:

```
public MyClass {

MyClass(){}

public static float runCalcs()
{
    float sum;
    Float[] floatArray = map.entrySet()
                        .stream()
                        .map(key -> key.getKey().getPrice())
                        .toArray(size -> new Float[size]);

    for(int i=0; i<floatArray.length; i++) {
        sum += floatArray[i];
    }   

    return sum;
}

}
```

My question is when I execute this method from a thread like so:

```
float retVal = MyClass.runCalcs();
```

Is this a thread safe execution of static method or do I need to synchronize or lock **MyClass.RunCalcs()** to make it thread safe. 
In my application, multiple threads will be executing this method simultaneously.
 Please let me know.
 Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where does `map` come from?

Comment: It depends if `map` (which must have some static context) can be updated by other threads while `runCalcs()` is executing.

Comment: map data is populated in another thread @Dominik Sandjaja

Answer (score 3):

Thread safety is not a questions about methods or classes.  Thread safety is a question about *shared data*.

Your shared data is not safe if a method running in one thread could temporarily put the data into a state that you would not want the same method or any other method running in a different thread to see.

Your `runCalcs()` method looks at `map` which presumably is a `Map` instance, and which presumably is shared with some other thread.

Is there any way that the other thread could change the contents of the map while `runCalcs()` is iterating over the map's `entrySet()`?  If so, then your code is not safe.

The way to make it safe is to change `runCalcs()` lock a lock while iterating, and also, change *every method* that could update `map` in a different thread to lock the *same lock* while changing `map`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @james large ! Yes the map data is shared by threads but each threads filters out data relevant to the work that needs to be performed and then updates an object in the map. I'll try the lock route